# Read a file using C++ and RAII

Tags: c++, raii

What's the best way to read a file in using C++ and RAII? All the examples I've seen use something similar to the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {

  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length]; // Seems wrong?

    is.read (buffer, length);

    delete[] buffer;
  }
}
```

According to what I know of RAII it seems wrong to initialize a char pointer and manually remove it.

I've done something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {

  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    std::shared_ptr<char> buffer = std::make_shared<char>();

    is.read (buffer.get(), length);
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if that's right either. I've also not been able to successfully cast `std::shared_ptr<char>` to a `std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>` if needed (or if it's possible, or if it even makes sense?).

Comment: there is an example with [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) on cppreference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> char * buffer = new char [length]; // Seems wrong?

It's not wrong, just ... unsafe.

Safer implementations:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer{new char [length]}; // note: use char[] as parameter
is.read (buffer.get(), length);
```

Better than previous:

```
std::vector<char> buffer{length, ' '};
is.read (buffer.data(), length);
```

or:

```
std::string buffer{length, ' '};
is.read (buffer.data(), length);
```

In particular, this is undefined behavior:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> buffer = std::make_shared<char>();
is.read (buffer, length);
```

because it allocates *one* character dynamically, then places up to length characters at that memory location. In practice, this is a buffer overflow, unless your length is always 1.

Comment: What does 'UB' mean?

Comment: Undefined behavior. It means the code is invalid, and there is no way to predict what the application will do when such code is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

std::shared_ptr (like other smart pointers) applies RAII to a single instance of an object (here a single char, oops !)

You're looking for std::vector, which you can preallocate by calling vec.reserve().

About casting it to uint8_t, I'd say that calling vec.data() once you have read your data in and casting the result to uint8_t should work as expected (I won't assert it is standard though).

Comment: Why couldn't you ? It's just about shaving off reallocations if you have a rough idea of what the read size will be.

Comment: because if you then try to push_back or pop_back it wont work as expected and the size of the vector will still be zero.

Comment: I think I don't get what you mean. Calling reserve() will allocate a buffer for future push_back()s. Of course the vector's logical size will still be zero, because we haven't inserted anything (yet). How would that be unexpected ?

Comment: It looks like you are suggesting you can just do a reserve and then use vec.data() in the read. if you want to this you have to either construct it to the right size (like you suggest) or use resize.

Comment: Oh, no I didn't mean that. I understood that the OP wanted to read data in (push_back()s inside), _then_ have the result cast to uint8_t*. Not the other way around (which would of course trump all advantages of using std::vector instead of a raw buffer)